# How to Re-Crawl My Website on Google?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, meta-description

I have one issue with my website. When I updated the meta title and description the first time, everything was fine and Google crawled the website within 24 hours. But now due to some keyword variations I had to change the title and description again.

As of now the new title is crawled by Google but the description is still the old one. I updated my site over a week ago but still the search results display the old description.

Does anyone know how much time it might take to index my website's description again so that I can rank on my targeted keyword?

Comment: I do not think that you need to do any manual action for this. Google will crawl fresh data automatically.

Comment: Also note that the description that appears in the SERPs is not necessarily the meta description from your pages. Google customises the description according to what the user searches for. Also, the meta description is not used for "indexing", so any "targeted keyword" will not help your ranking - other than maybe click-through rates.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a couple of hours, sometimes a couple of days, in rare cases one or two weeks.

Can't really give you a better answer really. It depends on your rank (how important are you to users (according to them)?), the amount of visitors, the amount of fresh content, the relevance of the page itself, dumb luck (e.g.: It's your turn again).

It also depends on how well those pages are to find, make sure you have your sitemap correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you attached the site to [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) (formerly: Google Webmasters Tools)?

Through the console, you can speed up the process by doing **Fetch as Google**. It fetches the page's info for you as Google would, then after it is completed, gives you the option to [submit the link to Google.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812)

To speed site crawl rates up overall, you can add your sitemap to Google Search Console as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google only decides about the crawling of any websites.It is based on several factors.One of the main factors is data freshness.Caffeine update http://googleblog.blogspot.in/2010/06/our-new-search-index-caffeine.html is mainly focused on that.

Mean While you can use https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?rd=1 Fetch & Render tool to know about the page rendering